# Elasticsearch basic client connection

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client

I have setup a SSH tunnel on port 9300 to my remote elasticsearch server.

When running this basic example to get the [example data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html) from the elasticsearch instance I get a "*org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available*"

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .build();

    Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), 9300));


    GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("bank", "account", "25").execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: What is the local port of your SSH tunnel? Also 9300? What version of ES are you running? How have you configured `network.host` in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file?

Comment: @Val local port of SSH tunnel is `9300`, ES version is `elasticsearch-2.3.3-1.noarch` default installation, which makes the `network.host localhost`

Comment: Then try `"localhost"` instead of `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`

Comment: I already tried this and get the error `failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...`

Comment: did you check server log?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy Good suggestion, it seems nothing is showing up in the logs, maybe there is something wrong with how I am connecting?

Comment: it could be, probably you should check it via 9200 and curl

Answer (score 0):

my setup is that i connect from my localhost to a remote machine where elasticsearch is running in a docker-container and i got the same problem on port 9300 using transportclient with netty4. connecting to the tunneled port 9200 was no problem

```
transport.publish_host: localhost
```

has fixed it

so my es.yml has now:

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 172.18.0.33
transport.publish_host: localhost
```

and i do the tunnel via:

```
ssh -N -L 9300:172.18.0.33:9300 user@server.com
```